# Need new house location added to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, address

We have recently built a new house in an existing subdivision.  I am registered with 911 and receiving mail at this address.  Street is not currently shown on Google maps.  How do I add my location to Google Maps so deliveries can find me.  I am also having problems with changing my address (getting invalid address messages) ... apparently since it does not currently show up in Google Maps.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: report the new information yourself.  Click on the "Send feedback" link at the bottom right of the map in a browser (it's very small print, at the edge of the window.) Then select "Wrong pin location or address." Or in the Android app, tap Contribute, then Edit Map. For further info, see this [Google Maps Community post](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/38802822?hl=en).

Option 2: ask your community to update the information in Google Maps, such as via Google's [Geo Data Upload](https://support.google.com/mapcontentpartners/answer/9359673?hl=en&ref_topic=21600) for Map Content Partners.  It is also possible that your community already does this, but the update has not yet been published.  (I would expect updates to be sent on a schedule rather than at every change, and it may also take time for Google to incorporate a submission.)
It's hard to say what office of your community would handle this.  Depending on the size of your community, it might be a city or county office.  Try starting with where you registered with 911.  Even if they don't submit updates, they likely know who else in your community manages address information.